# Extract TLDs , SLDs from a dataframe column into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to extract the top level domain (TLD), second level (SLD) etc from a column in a dataframe and added to new columns. Currently I have a solution where I convert this to a list and then use `tolist`, but the since this does sequential append, it does not work correctly. For example if the   url has 3 levels then the mapping gets messed up

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4],"C":["xyz[.]com","abc123[.]pro","xyzabc[.]gouv[.]fr"]})
    
    df['C'] = df.C.apply(lambda x: x.split('[.]'))
    
    df.head()
    
        A   B   C
    0   1   2   [xyz, com]
    1   2   3   [abc123, pro]
    2   3   4   [xyzabc, gouv, fr]

d = [pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col) for col in df.columns]


df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)

df.head()

    A0  B0  C0     C1   C2
0   1   2   xyz    com  None
1   2   3   abc123 pro  None
2   3   4   xyzabc gouv fr
```

I want C2 to always contain the TLD (com,pro,fr) and C1 to always contain SLD
I am sure there is a better way to do this correctly and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the `Cx` columns:

```
df.loc[:, "C0":] = df.loc[:, "C0":].apply(
    lambda x: x.shift(periods=x.isna().sum()), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A0  B0      C0      C1   C2
0   1   2     NaN     xyz  com
1   2   3     NaN  abc123  pro
2   3   4  xyzabc    gouv   fr
```

Comment: Thank you that will work for sure. Is this 3 step (converting to a list, aggregating and then shifting) way only way to do it or is there a better way handle this?

Comment: @K3rn3l5 I think it's ok, if performance is enough. I'd do `df = pd.concat([df[["A", "B"]], df.C.apply(lambda x: x.split("[.]")).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("C"),], axis=1)` but its essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regex with negative lookup and `split` builtin `pandas` with `expand`

```
df[['C0', 'C2']] = df.C.str.split('\[\.\](?!.*\[\.\])', expand=True)
df[['C0', 'C1']] = df.C0.str.split('\[\.\]', expand=True)
```

that gives

```
   A  B                   C      C0   C2    C1
0  1  2           xyz[.]com     xyz  com  None
1  2  3        abc123[.]pro  abc123  pro  None
2  3  4  xyzabc[.]gouv[.]fr  xyzabc   fr  gouv
```